# Uploading data from Excel to DB in PHP making size issues

Tags: php, arrays, performance, excel

I have to upload excel and read data then writing to DB. I need to get data from 2mb excel file. I have done coding up to reading excel data. While uploading excel there was shown some issues

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20 bytes)
```

I have solved this by using

```
 ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

and also execution time issues that also somehow managed by

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

the problem is when I'm trying to upload excel size more than 300kb, it taking too much to complete the execution. Can anyone suggest me best way to read data from excel ? Is there any performance issue if I'm storing the values to an array before inserting to DB ?

Adding my codes here

```
<?php

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
include('../includes/class_read_xl.php');
$obj_read_xl=new class_read_xl();
if(isset($_POST["upload"])) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"], "../uploads/xlsheet/" . $_FILES["ufile"]["name"]);
    $file = $_FILES['ufile']['name'];
    $inputFileName = '../uploads/xlsheet/'.$file;
    //$inputFileName = "test.xls";
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);
    // Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    $total_sheets=$objPHPExcel->getSheetCount(); // here 4
    $allSheetName=$objPHPExcel->getSheetNames(); // array ([0]=>'student',[1]=>'teacher',[2]=>'school',[3]=>'college')
    //print_r($allSheetName);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); // first sheet
    $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); // here 5
    $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // here 'E'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);  // here 5
    //exit();
    $arr_data=array();
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
        $value = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
         if(is_array($arr_data) ) {
            $arr_data[$row-1][$col]=$value;
         }
        }
    }

    print_r($arr_data);     
}
?>
```

Comment: `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` is really a bad idea !

Comment: We can't help unless you post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look as though you're using any of the recommended memory saving methods such as cell caching or "chunking", which are described in the PHPExcel documentation - see section 4.2.1 of the developer documentation (entitled "Cell Caching", and various sections of the User documentation for Reading Spreadsheet files.

If you're only actually reading data from a single worksheet in the file, just load that one worksheet, not all four

Storing values to an array will significantly increase the memory requirements of the script, because your array will also take up memory. However, rather than reading every cell in a row individually, you could use the rangeToArray() method for each row, which wouldn't be such a big memory overhead, and is faster than reading each individual cell